# Submitting form via ajax in Laravel 5.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, laravel-5.1

I'm struggling to get this form to submit using ajax and Laraval 5.1. I've been searching and trying for a few days with very little success. Here is as close as I can can get currently. Submitting the form results in a successful 200 POST status, but the console comes up empty? The database is supposed to be updated, but is not, so I have to assume that  the data is not being sent from the form properly. The jquery version used here is 2.1.4. The form is located within a modal popup, incase that might have any effect.

Here is my code:

Form:

```
        <form id="addVendorForm" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" 
            action="{{URL::to('admin/settings/vendors/add-vendor')}}">
            <!-- Hidden input fields -->
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="shop_id" value="{{$data['shop_id']}}">

            <!-- Vendor Name -->
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label for="vendor_name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Vendor</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                        name="vendor_name" id="vendor_name" 
                        placeholder="Vendor name"
                        required
                        value="{{ old('vendor_name') }}">
                </div>
                </div><!-- /.form-group -->

                <!-- Vendor Phone -->
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label for="vendor_phone" class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" 
                        name="vendor_phone" id="vendor_phone" 
                        placeholder="Phone"
                        value="{{ old('vendor_phone') }}">
                </div>
                </div><!-- /.form-group -->

                <!-- Vendor Email -->
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label for="vendor_email" class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" 
                        name="vendor_email" id="vendor_email" 
                        placeholder="Email"
                        value="{{ old('vendor_email') }}">
                </div>
                </div><!-- /.form-group -->


                <!-- Address -->
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label for="address_1" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Address</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                        name="address_1" id="address_1" 
                        placeholder="Street address"
                        value="{{ old('address_1') }}">
                </div>
            </div><!-- /.form-group -->
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label for="address_2" class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                        name="address_2" id="address_2" 
                        placeholder="Apartment, suite, unit, building, floor, etc."
                        value="{{ old('address_2') }}">
                </div>
                </div><!-- /.form-group -->

                <!-- City -->
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label for="city" class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                        name="city" id="city" 
                        placeholder="City, town"
                        value="{{ old('city') }}">
                </div>
                </div><!-- /.form-group -->

                <!-- State/Province/Region -->
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label for="state_region" class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                        name="state_region" id="state_region" 
                        placeholder="State, province, region, territory, etc."
                        value="{{ old('state_region') }}">
                </div>
                </div><!-- /.form-group -->

                <!-- Country -->
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label for="country" class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                        name="country" id="country" 
                        placeholder="Country"
                        value="{{ old('country') }}">
                </div>
                </div><!-- /.form-group -->

                <!-- Postal Code -->
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label for="postal_code" class="col-sm-3 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                        name="postal_code" id="postal_code" 
                        placeholder="Postal code"
                        value="{{ old('postal_code') }}">
                </div>
                </div><!-- /.form-group -->

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button id="submitVendor" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Vendor</button>         
        </div>
    </form>
```

Route:

```
Route::post('admin/settings/vendors/add-vendor', 'JsonController@addVendor');
```

Controller Method:

```
    public function addVendor(Request $request) 
{

    // validate new vendor form
    $this->validate($request, [
        'vendor_name' => 'required|min:2|max:255',
        'vendor_phone' => 'phone:AUTO,US,CA',
        'vendor_email' => 'email|max:255',
        'address_1' => 'max:255',
        'address_2' => 'max:255',
        'city' => 'max:255',
        'state_region' => 'max:255',
        'country' => 'max:255',
        'postal_code' => 'max:255'
    ]);

    // if validation passed, store new vendor in database
    $vendor = new Vendor;
    $vendor->shop_id = $request->shop_id;
    $vendor->vendor_name = $request->vendor_name;
    $vendor->vendor_phone = $request->vendor_phone;
    $vendor->vendor_email = $request->vendor_email;
    $vendor->address_1 = $request->address_1;        
    $vendor->address_2 = $request->address_2;
    $vendor->city = $request->city;
    $vendor->state_region = $request->state_region;
    $vendor->country = $request->country;
    $vendor->postal_code = $request->postal_code;        
    $vendor->save();

    $data['vendor_id'] = $vendor->id;
    $data['vendor_name'] = $vendor->vendor_name;

    // return data
    return response()->json($data);

}
```

Javascript:

```
    // add-vendor.js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // process the form
 $('#addVendorForm').submit(function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '../../admin/settings/vendors/add-vendor/',
                data: $('#addVendorForm').serialize(),
                success : function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(errors){
                    console.log(errors);
                }
            });

            e.preventDefault();
        });            

});
```

Thank you so much for your help. This is my first attempt at submitting a form without a page reload.

Cheers.

Comment: Try `dd($request);` in your `addVendor()` to make sure the attributes are presented.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki. Thanks for mentioning the dd() function. It helped get some information into the console that helped me discover my actual error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm regretful to admit that I spent days thinking that the problem must have been with the ajax request, but it turns out to have been a routing issue. I'll post my solution here in hopes of preventing another newbie like myself from making the same mistake.

I set up a bunch of routes for creating, showing, editing, updating etc. and placed the route to the ajax form handler last.

```
// vendors
Route::get('admin/settings/vendors', 'Admin\VendorController@index');
Route::get('admin/settings/vendors/create', 'Admin\VendorController@create');
Route::post('admin/settings/vendors', 'Admin\VendorController@store');
Route::get('admin/settings/vendors/{id}', 'Admin\VendorController@show');
Route::post('admin/settings/vendors/{id}', 'Admin\VendorController@update');
Route::get('admin/settings/vendors/{id}/edit', 'Admin\VendorController@edit');
Route::post('admin/settings/vendors/add-vendor', 'JsonController@addVendor');
```

The router obviously checks for matching routes sequentially until it finds one, so "add-vendor" at the end of "admin/settings/vendor/add-vendor" was being caught as a parameter in "admin/settings/vendor/{id}" and the data was posted to the wrong controller method.

Simply renaming the route so there could be no confusion between it and the other controller was the easy answer!